# MVC Ajax.beginform Custom Confirmation Dialogue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to implement my own confirmation dialogue with the following?

```
Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Confirm ="" })
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you did not find the answer, check the (OnBegin) function implemented in the following question:
[Ajax.BeginForm Confirmation Dialog onBeginForm() before triggering OnSuccessForm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103702/ajax-beginform-confirmation-dialog-onbeginform-before-triggering-onsuccessform)

Answer (score -1):

Ajax BeginForm sends data to Controller.
You need to use Ajax ActionLink
İn order to show some confirm message try below :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"Revoke Access to all Galleries Immediately", 
"ViewInvites", 
"Gallery", 
new AjaxOptions { 
Confirm = "Are you sure you want to revoke access to all galleries? This cannot be    undone.",
HttpMethod = "Post"
}
)
```

Comment: The Ajax.BeginForm lets you initiate a Confirmation dialogue just like the ActionLink method. I was curious whether I could have my own confirmation function not just a message.